# SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm trying to use OpenSSL to connect to an SSL server.

When I run:

```
openssl s_client -connect myhost.com:443
```

The following SSL client configurations work just fine:

- Windows (`OpenSSL 0.9.83e 23 Feb 2007`)
- Linux (`OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`)
- Linux (`OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010`)

Output from any successful connection looks like this:

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DES-CBC3-SHA
    Session-ID: (hidden)
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: (hidden)
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1337266099
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

However, when I use client with my Ubuntu 12.04 (w/ `OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012`) I get error:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
...:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
```

How can I proceed on solving this?

All tips are much appreciated!

Comment: What protocol and cipher are used when it connects from Windows?

Comment: It says: `New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DES-CBC3-SHA`. I wish I understood what this all means! :)

Comment: DES?  That's an odd cipher to have highest priority.  What kind of server are you connecting to?

Comment: Have you used something like Wireshark to take a look at the packets and exactly what is going on? You could run this at either end.

Comment: No I haven't. Wireshark seems awesome. Thanks for the tip! I will try it out soon.

Comment: Maybe the defaults on the newer openssl are by default restricting older ssl protocol versions? There would be some reasons to do so given the recent BEAST mess...

Comment: What is the version of the SSL _client_ you're using to attempt connection?

Comment: Well basically all versions I have listed so far are client versions. I don't even know what SSL software the server uses! Sorry if that wasn't clear enough!

Comment: D'oh, understood. You're testing the clients against your site.

Comment: This problem is solved. I downgraded to `OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011` and it works.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This looks to be a known issue with Ubuntu's 1.0.1 OpenSSL: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371

It doesn't look like a fix is available. If possible you could downgrade to 1.0.0.

Try `openssl s_client -tls1 -connect myhost.com:443`

Comment: More details of the problem on the Debian ticket: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=665452

Comment: P.S. I will give you the bounty when it expires (19 hours)

Comment: Sounds good :) Final piece of info, upstream ticket with OpenSSL that seems to be the root cause of the issue: http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2802&user=guest&pass=guest

Comment: Thanks! This answer also works for OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016 on Mac

Answer (score 4):

This error can be caused by an older version of openssl when it can not re-negotiate the cipher (I generated a self-signed certificate using elliptic curves).

Specifically, I was getting the same error on MacOS with default openssl - 0.9.8zh

After installing the brew version OpenSSL 1.0.2f the error went away:

```
~/bin/openssl s_client -connect localhost:45678 | grep Cipher

verify return:1
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

Comment: after doing a brew install, my openssl version in /usr/bin/openssl was the old version. I had to specifically go to /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2o_2/bin to run the latest version of openssl

Answer (score 2):

If you get this issue with a Java HTTPS server running on OpenJDK, try editing `/etc/java-7-openjdk/security/java.security` and commenting out the line

```
security.provider.10=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/lib/security/nss.cfg
```

as discovered by [Christoph W](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/1006776).