# How can I downgrade OpenSSL to 1.0.0 in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl

How can I downgrade OpenSSL to 1.0.0 in Ubuntu?

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. Sadly, [there is a problem with OpenSSL 1.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/389197/ssl-routinesssl23-writessl-handshake-failure) and I would need to downgrade to version 1.0.0.

How can I do it the easiest way?

When I run:

```
sudo apt-cache madison openssl
```

Only versions 1.0.1 get listed.

All tips are appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever try this? Was it sucsessful? Was it because of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371?comments=all

Comment: Yes that was exactly the bug that caused me to downgrade. Due to other reasons we ended up reinstalling the whole OS from scratch (downgraded to earlier Ubuntu).

Comment: But, did the downgrade work? It sounds like you never put it into production, though... I was also wondering if there were any ill effects or security problems with doing this

Comment: Yes the downgrade worked. I don't know in detail about the security implications, but if you ask me I'd much rather have a 99% secure service online than 100% secure service offline.

Answer (score 2):

apt-get has a feature called Pinning, which addresses your problem. Details can be found in this [how-to](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-pin)

Comment: This sounds great. I'm reading the docs, but I would really like to hear more help!

Comment: What sort of help do you need? Have you already tried creating/editing /etc/apt/preferences and making an entry for openssl?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to download the [.deb package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/1.0.0g-1ubuntu1). It is the 1.0.0g version of OpenSSL. next you could just install it from the .deb. I have never done a downgrade from OpenSSL myself so you better do not try this on production systems.