# Forcing NGINX upstream server connection to particular tls version and cipher

Tags: nginx, ssl

My question is very similar to what is already mentioned in:
[Forcing a particular SSL protocol for an nginx proxying server](https://serverfault.com/questions/436737/forcing-a-particular-ssl-protocol-for-an-nginx-proxying-server?newreg=9d3b4636b3aa4c9cb78479570d7af527)

Except here the workaround is to lower down the ssl version, in my case it is not. 
Below is my topology. I am trying to simulate a F5 like SSL proxy on both client and server ( frontend and backend (supposedly upstread in NGINX terms)).

SSL client---TLS1.3---->NGINX proxy--TLS1.3---> SSL server

My frontend works fine and TLS1.3 handshake is good, but my upstream expects TLS1.3 as well and thats where i found the problem. 
No matter what i setup in the NGINX conf file, it always forward the TLS1.2 version and corresponding ciphers to the real servers and those gets rejected.
If I use the TLS1.2 on my server end then the handshake is successful.

I even tried to force the versions by just mentioning TLS1.3 in the list but didn't get success.

Below is the snippet of my nginx config.

---

```
upstream pool_transparent {
zone        test_pool_zone 64k;
server      X.0.0.1:443;
server      X.0.0.2:443;
server      X.0.0.3:443;
server      X.0.0.4:443;
}

server {
listen                          443 ssl default_server;
status_zone                     test;
ssl_certificate                 certs/x.crt;
ssl_certificate_key             certs/x.key;
ssl_protocols                   TLSv1.3;
ssl_ecdh_curve                  secp521r1:secp384r1:prime256v1:X25519;
#ssl_ciphers                    HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_ciphers                     TLS-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SH\                               A256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
ssl_session_cache               shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout             10m;

location / {
    proxy_pass                  https://pool_transparent;
    proxy_ssl_protocols         TLSv1.3;
    #proxy_ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    proxy_http_version          1.0;
    proxy_set_header            Connection "";
    proxy_set_header            Host $host;
}

location @health_check {
    proxy_pass                  https://pool_transparent;
    proxy_set_header            Host $host;
    health_check                uri=/ interval=10 fails=1 passes=1;
}
}

server {
listen                          8080; 

location /api {
    limit_except GET {
        auth_basic              "NGINX Plus API";
        auth_basic_user_file    /home/rakesh/passwdfile;
    }

    api                         write=on;
    #allow                      0.0.0.0/0;
    #deny                       all;
}

location = /dashboard.html {
    root                        /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location /swagger-ui {
    root                        /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your Nginx version. From memory you run "nginx -v" to find the version.

Comment: is the ssl_ciphers line supposed to finish with an apostrophe as well as a semi-colon?



:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';